# react-navigation v5: Exception thrown: createStackNavigator is not a function

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am very new to React, if you need any more information let me know and I can provide. I am trying to add bottom tabs. I have followed the react-navigation documentation to the best of my ability. I have also scoured the forms and found a few similar questions, but still could not work it out. Thank you for the help.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
    import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
    import Icon from 'react-native-ionicons';
    import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
    import GreenScreen from "./GreenScreen";
    import RedScreen from "./RedScreen";

const GreenStack = createStackNavigator ();

function GreenStackScreen() {
    return (
        <GreenStack.Navigator>
            <GreenStack.Screen name="Green" component={GreenScreen}/>
            <GreenStack.Screen name="Red" component={RedScreen}/>
        </GreenStack.Navigator>
    );
}

const RedStack = createStackNavigator ();

function RedStackScreen() {

    return (
        <RedStack.Navigator>
            <RedStack.Screen name="Green" component={GreenScreen}/>
            <RedStack.Screen name="Red" component={RedScreen}/>
        </RedStack.Navigator>
    );
}


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function BottomTabs() {
    return (
            <Tab.Navigator
                screenOptions={({route}) => ({
                    tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => {
                        let iconName;

                        if (route.name ==='Green') {
                            iconName='home'

                        }else if(route.name ==='Red'){
                            iconName='grid'
                        }
                        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={20} />
                    }
                })} >
                <Tab.Screen name="Green" component={GreenStackScreen}/>
                <Tab.Screen name="Red" component={RedStackScreen} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Comment: `import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';`
`import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';`

Comment: Stop the metro bundler and re-build the app. I mean simply kill the terminal and re-run the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your imports are wrong
You should import like below

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

And the bottom navigator should be imported like below

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the way WebStorm suggested to me. In any case, I changed it according to your suggestion and there is no change.

Comment: You have installed the correct npm packages right? restart the bundler try again

Comment: It appears there are two exceptions.. createStackNavigator is now recognised as a function, but the same exception is occurring elsewhere. I'll make sure all my imports are correct, thanks again